# Can we make all the cockroach and mosquito extinct by eating them?

Tags: earth-like, food

Suppose there is a world like Earth, except the dominant cultures of the planet enjoy eating cockroaches and mosquitoes.

Humans have driven plenty of animals to extinction. Is it possible for humans to make cockroaches and mosquitoes extinct by eating them?

If so, what level of human technological development would be required to make either one of them go extinct?

Comment: @Mołot upvotes=4 ,i don't get what is wrong

Comment: This question was clearly off-topic, since it was about our world and not about worldbuilding. I have heavily edited to make it about a theoretical world.

Comment: *Most of us* enjoy eating cows, and we haven't driven them to extinction.  In fact, they're thriving so well (in captivity) that [they're contributing a significant amount of methane to climate change.](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2014/04/cow-farts-really-significantly-contribute-global-warming/)  (18% of greenhouse gases released per year, as compared to roughly 11% IIRC, from all the cars in the world.)

Comment: Well, all the insectivorous birds and bats (and other insects, such as dragonflies) sure haven't managed to drive mosquitos to extinction by eating them :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not from simple hunting, we couldn't even wipe them out by trying to do only that, not without taking a large part of the biosphere with them and even then its not a guarantee. We have been actively trying to exterminate them for decades in some places and can't manage it. They breed to fast and are too hardy.

Human over hunt megafauna, things that breed slowly and are fairly easy to find, or things that have a weakness we can easily exploit like the swarm breeding passenger pigeons or immobile clams.

Answer (score 5):

For one thing, we would spend more energy catching them than we would get from eating them.

For another, we can't catch them faster than they can breed.

We could possibly make a targeted virus that kill them off.  There's nothing that can go wrong with **that** plan....

Comment: Given how resilient cockroaches are, I wonder what a virus that can kill them could do... to the rest of us.

Comment: Hence, my remark.